# modular form -Petersson inner product

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

my question is about Petersson inner product.
i need to prove that $(E_k,f) =0 $  $\forall f \in S_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$

the only thing that i think that should help me is that the space of cusp form 
has a basis of Hecke eigenform.
i cant use in the Hermitian property of the Hecke operator (i dont think that help)  because is work only in the case both function are cusp but $E_k $ isnt a cusp form.

i know that $M_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z})=<E_k> \oplus S_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$

thank

Answer (score 2):

here is the prove :

Lemma 1 :  $E_k $ is eigenfunction $\forall  \space T_n $
Lemma 2 :  $ (T_nE_k,g) = (E_k,T_ng)$ $\space  \forall g\in S_k $
Lemma 3: there is a basis $\{f_1,...f_m\}$ of $S_k$ such that is simulation eigenfunction $\forall T_n $
please note that $\{f1 ,... f_m,E_k\}$ is basis for $M_k$ and by multiplication we can assusme that$ a_1(f'_1)=...=a_1(f'_m)=a_1(E'_k)=1$.

so it will be enough to show that $(f'_i,E_k)= 0$ $ \space  0 < i <m+1$
now we know that if $a_1(f)=1  => T_n(f) =a_n(f)f.$
so if there exist n such that $a_n(f'_i) \neq   a_n(E'_k)$ we finish.
assume not then $ \forall n>0  \space a_n(f'_i) =   a_n(E'_k)$ 
then $ g=f'_i-E_k \in M_k $ however when we look at fourier series we see that g=1. when we know the only constant function in $M_k$ are zero.   contradiction

i think it should work what do you think?